# MAGMA questions: better on SO or Math SE?

Tags: discussion

I asked two MAGMA questions, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486649/log-files-in-magma/26811055#26811055) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507751/magma-nilpotencyclass-being-miscalculated). Neither received an answer (save for mine in number 1), despite being there for ages on end. Then I saw a MAGMA question on math.SE. So I wondered: are MAGMA questions more fit for math.SE than Stack Overflow? In particular, is there any reason why they should be more likely to receive answers on either site?

PS: I sure hope to invoke the meta effect on question number 2 :).

**Note**

[THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system)) is the MAGMA I'm talking about. Something that no-one here seems to know about. I really wonder why everybody here sees MAGMA and assumes I'm talking about a Linear Algebra library, when I'm talking about the CAS. Especially when I posted an answer (currently the only one) saying "better choose MSE because there is no [magma-cas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magma-cas) tag here", whereas there is one over at MSE.

Comment: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewforum.php?f=2

Comment: I just registered and logged in there. How do I post? I see no "post" button.

Comment: OK, scratch that out, after _ages_ of searching I finally found a `newtopic` button and am now posting.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not know there were two MAGMAs, but you should have checked my questions before directing me to the wrong forum.

Comment: [Here's what I posted there](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1153).

Comment: Well, I did.  That it took you this long to figure out that you've been using the wrong [tag] takes different kind of help.  I'm not a surgeon.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no tag for the MAGMA computational algebra system here, but only one for the MAGMA GNU linear algebra library, something I only just found out about, I guess the answer is: post on Math SE, since no-one will ever answer over here. Or maybe I should propose the creation of a [magma-cas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magma-cas) tag. What do you think?